# Inheriting files in specific div through php files

Tags: php, html

I've created a file called menu.php to be my universal nav/menu file. The way it was created using bootstrap though, I have a div called article at the bottom which serves as the main body of the app, since the sidebar in my menu is expandable/responsive.

I really want to have one global menu file. I'm currently including it in all of my content pages like so:

```
<?php include("menu.php")?>
```

This works but it breaks my formatting. What I'm trying to do is make all of my main pages such as index.php have the html formatted so that it will always sit inside the  tag in my code below which shows card classes.

```
<header>
    <div class="branding">
        <div class="menu-button menu-toggle nav">
            <i class="material-icons">menu</i>
        </div>
        <img src=""  />
    </div>
    <div class="page-details">
    </div>
    <div class="settings">
        <div class="menu-button profile">
            <i class="far fa-user-circle fa-2x"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="menu-button menu-toggle aside">
            <i class="material-icons">chat</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="app">
    <nav>
        <div class="title-block">
            <img src="" />
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="material-icons">home</i>
                <span>Home</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <!--This following article section is the main body of the page, that I want each additional page to take up-->
    <article>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
        <div class="card"></div>
    </article>
</div>
```

Example:

Menu.php is my global menu/nav file but it makes the page/app act as a wrapper for all the other pages (index.php, editor.php, etc.)

menu.php

```
  <div class="app">
   <nav>
    Nav menu content
   </nav>

  <article>
    This will be the main page article for index.php, editor.php,etc.
  </article>
  </div>
```

example with index.php (the start and end are just hypothetical to show the endpoints)

```
<body>
<?php include("menu.php");?>
<?php start('article') ?>

<!--Everything from here to the end() call would be inserted in the article tags on menu.php-->

<div class="app">
  <div id="content">
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #A9BD50; ">Content Management Editor</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      <textarea id="mytextarea"></textarea>
    </form>
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center; color: #A9BD50; ">Preview</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php end() ?>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are trying to `include` the file `menu.php` inside of the `<article>` tags?

Comment: No the article tags are part of menu.php. I'm including menu.php in index.php and I'd like to wrap the content in index.php so that I can put that content into the article tags. So menu.php is sort of the global wrapper

Comment: I'm not pooh-poohing what you're doing here, but I am having difficulty understanding it. Are you saying that you're wrapping whole php page files inside `<article>` tags, and then wrapping these inside your navigation file? Can you create a visual of your page structure?

Comment: I just added an example, let me know if that helps at all

Comment: @Parapluie I got it to work with the package here https://arshaw.com/phpti/ but I was hoping to do it with my own code. Seems like it may be more than i though